# Angular Routing not happening for Login screen

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Following is my App.js code:

```
'use strict';

/* App Module */

var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'phonecatAnimations',

  'phonecatControllers',
  'phonecatFilters',
  'phonecatServices'
]);

phonecatApp.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',
  function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider. 
    when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
        controller: 'PhoneLoginCtrl'
      }).
      when('/phones', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/phone-list.html',
        controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'
      }).
      when('/phones/:phoneId', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/phone-detail.html',
        controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/login'
      });
  }]);
```

Following is my Controller.js code:

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */

var phonecatControllers = angular.module('phonecatControllers', []);

phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneLoginCtrl', ['$scope','$userInfoService','$location',
 function($scope,$userInfoService,$location){
    $scope.check = false;
     $scope.message = null;         
    //$scope.user = {};
    $scope.loginUser=function()
    {
        var username=$scope.user.name;
        var password=$scope.user.password;
        if(username=="admin" && password=="admin123")
        {
            //page.setUser($scope.user);
            $location.path( "/phones" );
        }
        else
        {
            $scope.message="Error";
            $scope.messagecolor="alert alert-danger";
        }
    }
 }]);

phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneListCtrl', ['$scope', 'Phone',
  function($scope, Phone) {
    $scope.phones = Phone.query();
    $scope.orderProp = 'age';
  }]);

phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'Phone',
  function($scope, $routeParams, Phone) {
    $scope.phone = Phone.get({phoneId: $routeParams.phoneId}, function(phone) {
      $scope.mainImageUrl = phone.images[0];
    });

    $scope.setImage = function(imageUrl) {
      $scope.mainImageUrl = imageUrl;
    }
  }]);
```

Though my other functions are working - phone-list and phone-detail but login page is not appearing. When I am invoking login page blank page is appearing. Please help. Following is the link to my project in Plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/zKXSOyRBg5ks42VL3YM8

Comment: See `console` for logged error

Comment: Does it show any error in the console?

Comment: No there are no errors in the console, i checked it.

Comment: Can you please put this in a plunker and share us the URL to inspect?

Comment: Put a console.log inside of your PhoneLoginCtrl and make sure it is being called.